# Rep exposure documentation

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

I am implementing a graph data structure in java. In this structure, vertices are represented as Vertex objects containing a private final String value field.

One of my methods vertices() returns the set of values of all vertices. In particular, a client who gets this set cannot get a particular value from the set and set it to another string (because of the final modifier). How should I document this behavior in the javadocs of vertices()?

Comment: What's the signature of the `vertices()` method?

Comment: public Set<String> vertices()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Java standard library doesn't have an interface for immutable collections.

I think all you can do is to wrap the Set you return in an `UnmodifiableSet` via `Collections.unmodifiableSet` and mention in the Javadoc that the Set being returned is immutable.